# Spring Data REST - prevent property edit based on role

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I use Spring Boot with Spring Data REST for data access and Spring Security for access restriction.

Assume I've got simple entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private Boolean isAuthorizedForClasifiedData;
}
```

I've got two roles in the application: USER and ADMIN.

Is there any simple way to prevent USER from changing value of **isAuthorizedForClasifiedData** while allowing ADMIN to update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I came up with is writing your own setter method.

```
public void setIsAuthorizedForClasifiedData(Boolean isAuthorizedForClasifiedData) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Optional<? extends GrantedAuthority> role_admin = authentication.getAuthorities().stream().filter(role -> role.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")).findAny();
    role_admin.orElseThrow(() -> new YourOwnForbiddenException());
    this.test = test;
}
```